# jQuery ajax is showing json from Asp.Net Core response

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

Stuck into a weird problem. My ajax call is showing response as following:

[image]

My ajax response is not going to success function.

Asp.Net Core code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public async Task<JsonResult> Create(CityCreateUpdateVm vm)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        var response = await _cityService.Create(vm);

        return Json(response);
    }

    return Json(new { });
}
```

_cityService service is returning following object:

```
public class AjaxResponseVm
{
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }

    public bool IsOk
    {
        get
        {
            return Errors.Count > 0 ? false : true;
        }
    }

    public AjaxResponseVm()
    {
        Errors = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddError(string error)
    {
        if (Errors != null && error != string.Empty)
        {
            Errors.Add(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<form asp-controller="city" asp-action="create" id="cityCreateFrom" method="post" onsubmit="return CreateResource('cityCreateFrom', 'City created successfully.')">
    <partial name="_CityInfo.cshtml" />
</form>
```

Parial view just have 2 text boxes.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
function CreateResource(formid, successfulmessage) {

var form = '#' + formid;

if ($(form).valid()) {

    Swal.fire(
        {
            type: "success",
            text: "Working...",
            allowOutsideClick: false
        });
    Swal.showLoading();

    $.ajax({

        type: form.attr('method'),

        url: form.attr('action'),

        data: form.serialize(),

        async: true,

        dataType: "json",

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (response) {

            Swal.close();

            if (response.isOk) {

                Swal.fire(
                    {
                        title: successfulmessage,
                        icon: "success",
                        type: "success",
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn bg-gradient-primary",
                        confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                    })
                    .then((result) => {

                        if (result.isConfirmed) {

                            window.location.href = 'index';
                        }
                    });
            }
            else {
               
                var errorList = '<ul>';

            }
        },

        error: function (response) {

            Swal.fire(
                {
                    title: "Something went wrong.",
                    icon: "error",
                    type: "error",
                    confirmButtonClass: "btn bg-gradient-danger",
                    confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                });
        },
    });
}

return false;
}
```

Response is correctly returning from Asp.Net Core. The problem is response is not going to the success function but it is showing JSON as shown in above picture.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards
D

**Update 1**

I don't know why it is submitting this request:

[image]

Not the content-type here. I don't know why it is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of json. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Can you post _cityService.Create pls?

Comment: @Serge: I have updated the question, added return response class from service.

Comment: How you submit your form ?  I can't see any button submit.

Comment: @Serge: It has a submit button with following code: <button class="btn bg-gradient-primary" type="submit" style="width: 140px !important"> Create</button>

Comment: Why are you returning the js function in onSubmit instead of just calling it there?

Comment: You mixed form submitting and ajax in your code. Plus you are using swal for some reason.   I don't see why  you need ajax here at all if you trying to submit form.  You have to select only one - a form or ajax or swal. Otherwise it will never be working.

Comment: @Serge:

Swal for showing loading status. Form submitting because I need to trigger jQuery validation. Ajax to do Async operation.

Comment: You are doing everything upside down. Make some research how to use ajax. You should return a partial view, not json. You have to redo all your code and I am sorry but I don't have time. It can take the whole day before everything will be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default form submit behavior, you should stop it if you want it submit with ajax.

```
<form asp-controller="city" asp-action="create" id="cityCreateFrom" method="post" onsubmit="return CreateResource(event, 'cityCreateFrom', 'City created successfully.')">
    <partial name="_CityInfo.cshtml" />
</form>
```

---

```
function CreateResource(event, formid, successfulmessage) {
    event.preventDefault()
    //...
}
```

Comment: Did exactly this and everything worked fine. Thank you. Cheers ^^